# convertToHHMM function

Tags: javascript, datetime, converting

Can someone help me make a more elegant solution to this function?

```
function convertToHHMM(info) {
var suffix='AM';
var hrs = parseInt(Number(info));  
var min = Math.round((Number(info)-hrs) * 60);
if (hrs >12) { hrs = hrs - 12; suffix='PM'; }
if (min < 10) {min='0'+min;}
return hrs + ':' + min + ' ' + suffix;
}
```

Comment: To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kinda hard to make it "more elegant", but it can certainly be made more *correct*.

Since you use `Math.round`, you can get a time like `"3:60 PM"` if you pass it `15.999`. And I'm preeeetty sure there's no such thing.

There's also another bug. If you pass a value like `0.5`, you *should* get `"12:30 AM"`. But you don't. You get `"0:30 AM"`.

And some nitpicking: First off, `info` is not a very descriptive name. It looks like you're trying to format a number of hours, with minutes as the decimals, so `hours` would be a better name. (Edit: or better yet `fractionalHours` as rolfl suggests, and which I forgot to credit.)

Also, instead of using `parseInt` (which is meant to turn a string into an integer), use `Math.floor`, which is what you actually mean: The number without any decimals. For the minutes, you could use the modulo operator (`%`) to get the remainder of dividing by 1 (i.e. the decimals) instead of subtracting. But either one works.

By the way, even if your input is a string like `"12.3231"` JavaScript's type coercion will treat it as a number, so you don't really *need* `Number()` anywhere, but it's fine to add it.

You can also do something slightly tricky by using modulo 12 on the hours, and default to 12 if the result it zero. That fixes the 0/12 bug mentioned above.

Also, fewer lines do not make things better/faster/more elegant. In this case, it just hurts readability. So use some linebreaks instead of having a line like `if (hrs >12) { hrs = hrs - 12; suffix='PM'; }`.

Lastly, use some indentation. It may just be a copy/paste thing when you created the question, but still.

I might do something like this, first converting everything to minutes and rounding *that*, then breaking it into hours and minutes afterward:

```
function convertToHHMM(fractionalHours) {
  var totalMinutes = Math.round(fractionalHours * 60) % (24 * 60),
      hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60) % 12 || 12,
      minutes = totalMinutes % 60,
      suffix = totalMinutes >= 12 * 60 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  if(minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;

  return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + suffix;
}
```

- `totalMinutes` rolls over after rounding, so passing in `23.999` is equivalent to passing in `0`, and `27` becomes `3`, etc.
- `hours` also roll over but start at 12 instead of zero, then 1, 2, 3 and so on.
- `minutes` should be straight-forward, and
- `suffix` basically looks at whether the `totalMinutes` are greater than or equal to noon-in-minutes.

Snippet with some test cases below (format borrowed from rolfl).

```js
function original(info) {
var suffix='AM';
var hrs = parseInt(Number(info));  
var min = Math.round((Number(info)-hrs) * 60);
if (hrs >12) { hrs = hrs - 12; suffix='PM'; }
if (min < 10) {min='0'+min;}
return hrs + ':' + min + ' ' + suffix;
}


function reviewed(fractionalHours) {
  var totalMinutes = Math.round(fractionalHours * 60) % (24 * 60),
      hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60) % 12 || 12,
      minutes = totalMinutes % 60,
      suffix = totalMinutes >= 12 * 60 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  if(minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;

  return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + suffix;
}

var testCases = [
  ["12:00 AM", 0],          // midnight
  ["12:30 AM", 0.5],
  ["1:00 AM",  0.99999999],
  ["11:30 AM", 11.5],
  ["12:00 PM", 11.9999999], // noon
  ["12:00 PM", 12],
  ["11:30 PM", 23.5],
  ["12:00 AM", 23.9999999],
  ["12:00 AM", 24],
  ["1:00 AM",  25]
];

var data = "<table>";
data += "<tr><th>Input</th><th>Expected</th><th>Review func</th><th>Original func</th></tr>";
for(var i = 0, l = testCases.length ; i < l ; i++) {
  data += "<tr>";
  data += "<td>" + testCases[i][1] + "</td>";
  data += "<td>" + testCases[i][0] + "</td>";
  data += "<td>" + reviewed(testCases[i][1]) + "</td>";
  data += "<td>" + original(testCases[i][1]) + "</td>";
  data += "</tr>";
}
data += "</table>";

document.body.innerHTML = data;
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace }
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td, th {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question really sucks, and it's a good example of why Code Reviews are important, and there is a lot to learn in it. I was ***very*** close to closing the code as "Does not work".

3 hours ago you were asked to give some clarification and context. You did not. So, let me show you how a programmer should present their code for review, because in there is a lesson too. This is approximately what your question should have looked like:

> My function takes a time and formats the time in Hours and Minutes
>   with a AM/PM suffix. The input time is in the format of a
>   floating-point number, so, for example, `14.5` is 14 and a half hours
>   after midnight, or `2:30PM`
>
> ```
> function convertToHHMM(info) {
>     var suffix='AM';
>     var hrs = parseInt(Number(info));  
>     var min = Math.round((Number(info)-hrs) * 60);
>     if (hrs >12) { hrs = hrs - 12; suffix='PM'; }
>     if (min < 10) {min='0'+min;}
>     return hrs + ':' + min + ' ' + suffix;
> }
> ```

Why is that text introduction necessary? Well, for a start, your code does not tell us what `info` is. It could be a time-since-epoch, it could be seconds-since-start-of-day, it could be ***anything***.

I had to struggle through WTF moments to understand why `parseInt(Number(info))` was necessary. How was I supposed to know that `info` was already a Number, and not a String, or some other object, like a Date. I had to understand that the ParseInt was important not because the input was a String, but because it was a floating-point number and you wanted just the integral part.

OK, so, having done the hard work of understanding how your function works, and what the inputs and outputs are, this is how I would write it....

... but first, the bugs in your code.

1. what if someone gives you the input `5.9999`. Your code will output `5:60AM` which makes no sense. The `Math.round()` of the minutes is a problem. You want to get `Math.floor()`.
2. your handling around noon is very problematic. You use `hrs > 12` to test for noon, but, that should be `hrs >= 12`. As it stands, your code says the input `12.50` is `12:30AM` when it should be `00:30PM`.

This is approximately how I would have written your function, given the above... I have compared it with yours using some input values to test with.

```js
function convertToHHMMX(fractionalHours) {
  var fHours = Number(fractionalHours);
  var hours = Math.floor(fHours);
  var minutes = Math.floor((fHours - hours) * 60.0);
  var fill = minutes < 10 ? '0' : '';
  var suffix = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours -= 12;
  }
  if (hours == 0) {
    // make 00:30AM / PM become 12:30AM / PM
    hours += 12;
  }
  return hours + ':' + fill + minutes + suffix;
}

function convertToHHMM(info) {
var suffix='AM';
var hrs = parseInt(Number(info));  
var min = Math.round((Number(info)-hrs) * 60);
if (hrs >12) { hrs = hrs - 12; suffix='PM'; }
if (min < 10) {min='0'+min;}
return hrs + ':' + min + ' ' + suffix;
}

var data = "YourFn     Monkey\n";
for (var t = 0; t < 24; t += 0.49999) {
  data += convertToHHMM(t) + "     " + convertToHHMMX(t) + "\n";
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
```

```html
<pre id="output">Output</pre>
```

Comment: I'm confused: `12.5` should be "12:30 PM". `0.5` should be "12:30 AM". There's no zero-hour if you use AM/PM notation. `Math.floor(fractionalHours) % 12 || 12` should get you the right result (albeit in a kinda tricky way)

Comment: Good point Flambino

Comment: > "3 hours ago you were asked to give some clarification and context. You did not."  I'm sorry.

Comment: changing ROFL's code to this seems to work better: 
Instead of: `if (hours >= 12) {`  make it  `if (hours > 12) {` and add `if (hours == 0) { hours = 12 } // midnight` before the return

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/24ar1mxu/)

Comment: Corrected the output of `00:??` times to be `12:??` times.

Comment: I remember this question. I felt the same way. I spent some long minutes trying to make sense of it. Finally I concluded that it just really sucked too much, and walked away angry, partly at the op, partly at myself to even bother about such underspecified non-programmer-ly question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is essentially converting military time in number format to 12-hour time.

**Suggestions**

- Instead of `parseInt()` you can use **[bitwise right-shifting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/5s9e947e(v=vs.94).aspx)** to efficiently strip decimals off a number. The advantages are both efficiency and avoiding potential problems when the input has a preceding 0. *(**EDIT:** Flambino pointed out in the comments that you can also use the [bitwise OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/066h456z(v=vs.94).aspx) operator `x | 0;` to accomplish the same thing!)*

  - use regular ol' bitwise rightshift `x >> 0` for potentially negative values for `x`
  - use unsigned bitwise rightshift `x >>> 0` when `x` is guaranteed to be positive
- Use the **modulus operator `%`** to get the remainder when a number is divided by another number.

  - You can use this to convert the hours to the range of 12, no matter how high it goes: `hrs %= 12;` Note that this will convert 12 to 0, so you'd need to check for 0 and change it to 12.
  - You can use this to get the decimal remainder for calculating the minutes: `var min = (+info % 1)*60 >>> 0;`
  - And finally, you can use this to determine whether the converted hour will be in the morning or the afternoon: `var suffix = hrs % 24 >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";`

Here's an example using those suggestions:

```
function convertToHHMM(info) {
    var hrs = (+(info) >>> 0);
    var min = (+(info) % 1) * 60 >>> 0;
    var suffix = hrs % 24 >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    hrs %= 12;
    if (hrs === 0) {
        hrs = 12;
    }
    return hrs + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min + " " + suffix;
}
```

**Side Notes**

`+info` is functionally equivalent to `Number(info)` but takes up less space; that's a personal preference rather than a recommendation. If you prefer `Number()` then stick with it.

Similarly, I used the **[ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx)** (`condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse`) syntax a few times to keep the code concise, but you may prefer If/Else statements for readability.

**Working Example**

Here's a code snippet to see it in action:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = convertToHHMM(+input);
};

function convertToHHMM(info) {
  var hrs = (+(info) >>> 0);
  var min = (+(info) % 1) * 60 >>> 0;
  var suffix = hrs % 24 >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  hrs %= 12;
  if (hrs == 0) {
    hrs = 12;
  }
  return hrs + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min + " " + suffix;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="1.5" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
<div id="output" />
```

Comment: Thriggle I like this code better than ROFL's.  It's not as readable, but seems more elegant.  Thanks for your work and informative comments.

Comment: You can also just use bitwise OR: `x | 0`. Shorter than shifting.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for pointing that out, Flambino

Comment: No prob. You can also _left_-shift zero places, or use XOR zero (`x ^ 0`). Basically, any bitwise operation in JS will treat the operands as a 32-bit signed integers - i.e. drop the decimals. This despite numbers in JS being 64-bit floats in every other context. So it's just a JS oddity, but useful one. Just make sure that whoever's reading your code knows the trick too, or it'll look like voodoo :)

Comment: There's a slight advantage to using unsigned bitwise rightshift `>>>` over other bitwise operations if you know that the number will be positive. Very large numbers will ruin the coercion such that `3000000000.5 | 0` results in `-1294967296`. Unsigned bitwise rightshift will still break when it's applied to large enough numbers, but the working range is higher.